# Match two sounds with a level of certainty

Tags: pro-tools, sound-effects, sound-design

For instance I would like to tell with what percentage of accuracy a recorded sound match those given by a preexistent library of sounds

Plus, is there any tool or algorith that could be used?

Comment: Are you looking for audio tools that will do this for you, or DSP techniques? If you are looking for DSP techniques, then consider moving this question over to [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that site, but an out-of-the-box tool would be very helpful, thoug

Comment: I don't know of a good tool offhand, but hopefully someone else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shazam (and various others) do this for entire songs. [This paper](http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/) describes how:

1. Beforehand, Shazam fingerprints a comprehensive catalog of music, and stores the fingerprints in a database.
2. A user “tags” a song they hear, which fingerprints a 10 second sample of audio.
3. The Shazam app uploads the fingerprint to Shazam’s service, which runs a search for a matching fingerprint in their database.
4. If a match is found, the song info is returned to the user, otherwise an error is returned.

I would imagine for short sounds you would do similar but sample much more frequently.

Comment: wow! I'm going to install it right away, thanks

Comment: Well the idea is there but thats not going to work for what he is asking for...unless he is doing music that is not going to work

Comment: I'm not into doing it myself at this moment, but it's good to know it is possible. I've installed the app in my phone, and the results are amazing. I guess the question that could suit better my requirement is ...is it posible? etc.. etc

Comment: Yes of course it is possible, I would say you would have to take a look into the Shazam API and then go from there